# Shell-Scripting (BASH): What is the best way to toggle a script "on/off" that isn't able to end itself?

Tags: bash, unix, process

I would like to have a script with an infinite loop, that kills all processes created by this script when it gets executed again.

So basically you start the script via terminal:

**bash poll.sh**

and it's running infinitely, you open another terminal and again

**bash poll.sh**

and all poll.sh processes will get killed.

What would be the best way to do that? My first thought was to set environment variables, something like **export POLLRUNNING=true** and poll.sh would implement something like **if [ $POLLRUNNING = true ]; exit 1**

My second idea was to work with **touch .isrunning** and statement to ask for that file.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pidof(8)` supports an `-x` flag to specify scripts; it also supports an `-o omitpid` flag to leave out specific pids. So:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDS=`pidof -o $$ -x poll.sh`

if [ x$PIDS != x ]
    then kill -s SIGTERM $PIDS
fi

sleep 10
```